# Search box & filter within Spring Roo generated UI

Tags: spring-roo

I am developing a Spring Roo app from scratch (using JSP) and would like to include searching/filtering into the list page of every controller.

Looking for I have found this post showing some sort of filtering based on active record finders methods but I need to use the repository pattern approach.

http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/spring-roo-open-source-rapid

Does Roo provides this sort of functionality?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roo directly not, but you can install and use gvNIX distribution. gvNIX 1.2.1 includes two addons that will help you:

1. Addon to move your project (all views or select views) to jQuery
2. Addon to move your list pages to Dandelion-Datatables that includes the filtering you commented above

To learn more about gvNIX:

- http://code.google.com/p/gvnix/ (english doc)
- http://gvnix.org/ (spanish doc)